# Deprecated code cleanup: Updating EntityManager to EntityFieldManagerInterface

Tags: 9

[EntityManager is deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityManager.php/class/EntityManager/8.2.x) so I am trying to update code for Drupal 9. The documentation says it should usually be changed to EntityTypeManager, but in this case the code is using `getFieldStorageDefinitions` so it needs to be `EntityFieldManagerInterface`.

I changed this line:

```
  $fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type);
```

To:

```
  $fields = \Drupal::EntityFieldManagerInterface()->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type);
```

Which gives this error when I run behat:

```
  [error]  Error: Call to undefined method Drupal::EntityFieldManagerInterface() in _drush_behat_get_entity_field_types() (line 95 of /app/drush/Commands/contrib/behat-drush-endpoint/behat.inc) #0 /app/drush/Commands/contrib/behat-drush-endpoint/behat.inc(123): _drush_behat_get_entity_field_types('node')
```

However, I don't understand this error, because [EntityFieldManagerInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFieldManagerInterface.php/function/EntityFieldManagerInterface%3A%3AgetFieldStorageDefinitions/8.2.x) does have `getFieldStorageDefinitions`.

How can I update entityManager to EntityFieldManagerInterface?

Here's the full function if that's useful:

```
function _drush_behat_get_entity_field_types($entity_type) {
  $return = array();
  $fields = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type);
  foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field) {
    if (_drush_behat_is_field($entity_type, $field_name)) {
      $return[$field_name] = $field->getType();
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: `EntityFieldManagerInterface()->getFieldStorageDefinitions`  clearly you need to learn what an interface is for 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EntityFieldManager has no shortcut in `\Drupal`, so you need to get it through `\Drupal::service()`:

```
$fields = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldStorageDefinitions($entity_type);
```